# I want a ffmpeg command that will zoom video every 4 second with transition effects

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I want a ffmpeg command that will zoom video 5 times with transition effects (up to down, down to up, right to left, left to right randomly) after every 4 seconds and zooming will last 2 seconds.

Currently I have this command which only zoom video but not with transition.

```
ffmpeg -i VIDEO.mp4 -vf "zoompan=z='if(gte(time,ld(1)+10),st(1,time)*0,if(ld(1),if(lt(time,ld(1)+3),2,1)))':d=1:x=iw/2-(iw/zoom/2):y=ih/2-(ih/zoom/2):fps=29.97" OUT.mp4
```

I'm not an expert so if you give me the command with a little bit explanation that will be enough.

Thank you.

Comment: You need a video editing package, like Premiere or Shotcut.

Comment: [xfade](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Xfade) might be the filter you're looking for. Also, consider chopping up the video (split+trim?) to apply one effect per time segment and concatenate them back together. It might make your filtergraph easier to follow. Finally, you may get a better answer on the Video Production community.